# How to Reset Select Drop down in VueJs

Tags: vue.js

I am new in vue js please help.

I have two dropdowns and that that dropdown create from loop

```
<select v-if="tour.city_expert == 2" v-model="selected[index]" class="form-control" :id="'city_expert_both'+index" v-on:change="intiTourCityExpert(index, $event)" :disabled="tour.is_disable==true">
<option value="" selected>Select City Expert</option>
<option value="Guideinperson">Guide in person</option>
<option value="AudioGuide">Audio Guide</option>
</select>
```

[image]

I as per image I want reset dropdown if I uncheck the checkbox but only reset single row as I uncheck the checkbox.

I set `v-model="selected[index]"` on dropdown and set code on uncheck `this.$set(this.selected, index, '');` but its not working.

Help

Answer (score 4):

I ran into similar situation, and following worked for me.
And to rest try following anywhere - this.selectedStatus = '0';

```
<select id="item_status" class="form-control" v-model="selectedStatus">
    <option value='0'></option>
    <option value='1'>One</option>
    <option value='2'>Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked perfectly for me, although I don't quite understand what property of the select element is being set?  I think that's an HTML question!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would do something like this:

1. Add an onchange event to the checkbox with its index:
   @change="onChange(index)"
2. In the methods object define the function
   onChange like this:

   methods: {
       onChange(index) {
           this.selected[index] = ''
       }
   }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset the value of dropdown on click on any other button or so, than just set it to `null`.

```
this.accountType = null;
```

My Dropdown:

```
            <ejs-dropdownlist
              v-model:value="accountType"
              :dataSource="accountTypesData"
              :select="accountTypeSelect"
              placeholder="Select a type"
            ></ejs-dropdownlist>
```